# Remove parts of a path from output - Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a list of install paths for tomcat on my ubuntu system. How would I strip off `/bin/bootstrap.jar` at the end of each line? I am struggling to accomplish this with `sed`.

List:

```
/opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
/opt/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar
/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Desired Output:

```
/opt/tomcat/
/opt/tomcat7/
/usr/share/tomcat9/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your input and description don't match: remove */bin/bootstrap.jar* but */opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar* -> */opt/tomcat/bin/*

`echo $line | sed -e 'sX/bin/bootstrap.jarXX'` Here the *X*s are delimiters -- `sed` lets you use any character as a delimiter so that you don't confuse yourself by using `/`.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for, may be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES_LIST=$(ls -A1 /path/to/folder | grep -E "\.(jar)");

for currFile in ${FILES_LIST[@]}; do
    FILENAME="${currFile%.*}";
    EXTENSION="${currFile##*.}"
    printf "Filename: ${FILENAME}, Extension: ${EXTENSION}\n";
done;
```